# Strange GUI Error

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'm using 2013 Mac Mini with OSX Maverick 10.9.4 installed.
I don't know how to google this one because it's randomly happened, everything's normal after boot up,  but here's the problem:

1. Suddenly rightclick not working
2. Mouse hover not working (no highlighted menu)
3. Drag items can't go off on click (it's like stick to the mouse
   cursor) and I need to press esc key several times to release it
4. System performance goes down (lots of loading)
5. Log out can't fix it.
6. I have to restart the machine to fix them all

It's happen like 2-3 times a day. Does anyone of you have experience to this problem?

Sorry for the broken english.
Hebbian

Comment: Things to check: are the batteries in the keyboard and the mouse still ok? does it occur on all user accounts or only on a specific one? any specific processing running (leave Activity Monitor open with the CPU tab to check) at the time of the problem?

Comment: Try a new mouse and/or plugging it into a different USB port.